Unable to get Qt/QML to load my translations (i18n)
I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here, but I have an example project where I'm trying to use qsTrIds for translations, and I'm having issues figuring out why my translations aren't loading properly - the QML dialog elements only show the qsTrIds, like 'press-me' and 'hello-world' instead of the translated text.
Source: https://github.com/StumpDragon/QtExampleApp
Using Visual Studio 2022 community and Qt 6.7
I've run config on the project, and edited the translation files, and then run:
cmake --build ..\build-QtExampleApp-Desktop_Qt_6_7_0_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\ --target update_translations

and
cmake --build ..\build-QtExampleApp-Desktop_Qt_6_7_0_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\ --target release_translations

Any idea where I might be going wrong?
Here I am hardcoding the one translation I've done - _en (my system defaults to using en-US if I use the foreach loop that's commented out.  I don't have such a translation - is Qt defaulting to remapping _en?
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    set_qt_environment();

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    if ( translator.load(":/i18n/QtExampleApp_en") ) {
        QCoreApplication::installTranslator(&translator);
    }
    /*const QStringList uiLanguages = QLocale::system().uiLanguages();
    for (const QString &locale : uiLanguages) {
        const QString baseName = "QtExampleApp_" + QLocale(locale).name();
        if (translator.load(":/i18n/" + baseName)) {
            app.installTranslator(&translator);
            break;
        }
    }*/


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/qt/qml/Main/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
        &app,
        [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.addImportPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/qml");
    engine.addImportPath(":/");



    engine.load(url);

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return app.exec();
}

CMakeLists.txt bits:
qt_add_translations(TARGETS QtExampleApp
    TS_FILE_DIR i18n
)

EDIT 2024-04-20:
So running in debugger, when I use following code:
QTranslator translator;

const QStringList uiLanguages = QLocale::system().uiLanguages();

for (const QString &locale : uiLanguages) {
    const QString baseName = "QtExampleApp_" + QLocale(locale).name();
    if (translator.load(":/i18n/" + baseName)) {
        app.installTranslator(&translator);
        break;
    }
}

The first language I have is en-US
And the debugger is looking for a translation in:
C:/appdev/Qt/6.7.0/msvc2019_64/translations
app.installTranslator send a language change event, and apparently calls QTranslator::load, which calls QTranslatorPrivate::do_load.
Specifically it ( QApplicationEngine.load)  calls:
bool QTranslator::load(const QLocale & locale,
                       const QString & filename,
                       const QString & prefix,
                       const QString & directory,
                       const QString & suffix)

It looks like the locale at that point is a default locale, in the call toQTranslator::load, locale.country is null, and locale.language is null.
So the finale path for the .qm file it tries to laod is
C:/appdev/Qt/6.7.0/msvc2019_64/translations/qt_en.qm
Interesting.  But it apparently doesn't work either, when I put my QtExampleApp.qm file in C:/appdev/Qt/6.7.0/msvc2019_64/translations/qt_en.qm
Now if I specify a locale of en-US to
if (translator.load(locale, ":/i18n/" + baseName)),
this calls:
bool QTranslator::load(const QString & filename, const QString & directory,
                       const QString & search_delimiters,
                       const QString & suffix)

Inside QTranslator.load, it's looking for resource :/i18n/QtExampleApp_en_US/en-US.qm
function variables passed in:

filename = "en-US
directory = ":/i18n/QtExampleApp_en_US"
search_delimiters = ""
suffix = ""


You're load translator should look something like this:
    QTranslator translator;
    if ( translator.load(QLocale(), "QtExampleApp", QLatin1String("_"), QLatin1String(":/i18n")) ) {
        QCoreApplication::installTranslator(&translator);
    }

Qt will use the current default locale (i.e. system locale) as reflected by QLocale() and determine which translation to load.
References:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtranslator.html#load-1
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linguist-manager.html


I've tried your suggestion and using procmon it looks like QtExampleApp never tried to load a file named that - so I assume it's supposed to be a resource in the application, but I'm not sure my build method is loading the messages into the right places?

Also updated with more findings through the debugger
